# How can I stop a Swing Timer after n seconds?

Tags: java, swing, timer

I'm trying to make an image twinkle with `RaffleImage();` while I'm executing the timer, my character is immune to any collision, I want it to be immune only for 2 seconds, so the timer get execute only for 2 seconds and then get finished.

I've tried subtracting `System.currentTimeMillis()` but any variable I create from this method, have always the same value, making me get a zero from that subtracting.

Do you know how I can stop or pause the timer after any elapsed time in seconds?

```
immuneTimer = new Timer(50, new ActionListener() {  
        @Override
    public synchronized void actionPerformed(ActionEvent e) {
    long initMillis = System.currentTimeMillis();
     if (System.currentTimeMillis() - initMillis > 2000 ) { // this substract gives me 0
        initImages();
        setImmune(false); // so this never reached
        immuneTimer.stop();
      } else {
            raffleImage(); //its executing like forever;
             }
      }
});
```

Comment: You should initialize the `initMillis` outside the `actionPerformed()` method.

Comment: There is no need to synchronize an event in a listener. All listener code executes on the Event Dispatch Thread.

Comment: @camickr im sorry, i was just trying to put a wait(); instead of stop but it throwed me illegalMonitorState Exception. so i put the "syncrhonize" just for trying :C

Answer (score 0):

The `Swing` timer fires a an `ActionEvent`.  From the event you can use `getSource()` to get the source of the event.  Cast that source to the swing timer `object` and use that to turn it off.

To know when to turn it off you need to have a variable `count` the number of times the swing timer is invoked.  When the variable reaches that amount, turn it off.

```java
int elapsedTime = 0;
int timerDelay = 50;
int max = 2000;
public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent ae) {
     elapsedTime += timerDelay; // you could use getDelay here but it
                                // is in milliseconds.
     if (elapsedTime >= max) {
        Timer s = (Timer)ae.getSource();
        s.stop();
     }
     // rest of code
}
```

Comment: but i dont want to stop it after a number of invoked times, i want it to stoped after 2 seconds. can i asume, if i've set a delay of 50 ms in the swingTimer constructor, it should be repeated for 2000/50 times?, and would that be my "max" value?

Comment: Exactly!  Or you could just set the duration to 50 and the max to 2000 and when the conditional is met, you stop the timer.  Perhaps a better name for `count` would be `elapsedTime`.  It makes more sense.  I will edit my answer to use better variable names.